# cx_Oracle how to run executemany() with Date and Datetime (ORA-01861)

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

How can I run `executemany` to insert Date and Datetime without error ORA-01861 -  literal does not match format string?

DB Structre

```
CREATE TABLE test_db(
    id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    strMsg VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    dt DATE NOT NULL,
    dt_time TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Python

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
from datetime import *

apiToDf={
    'strMsg':[
        'AA',
        'BB',
        'CC',
        'DD'
    ],
    'dt':[
        '2022-02-01',
        '2022-02-02',
        '2022-02-03',
        '2022-02-04'
    ]
}

df=pd.dataframe(apiToDf)


data = []
PROCESS_TIME = datetime.now()

for ind in df.index:
    dataList = []
    paramOne = df['strMsg'][ind]
    paramTwo = datetime.date(df['dt'][ind])
    paramThree = PROCESS_TIME
    
    dataList.append(paramOne)
    dataList.append(paramTwo)
    dataList.append(paramThree)
    dataTupe = Tuple(dataList)

conn = cx_Orace.connet('Test','123456','127.0.0.1/testDb')
cursor = conn.cursor()
target_tb = 'test_db'
script = "insert into {tb} values (:1, :2, :3)".format(tb=target_tb)
cursor.executemany(script, data)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we convert the data to Tuple, we can use `executemany` normally.

```
    PROCESS_TIME = datetime.now()
    for ind in df.index:
        paramOne = df['strMsg'][ind]
        paramTwo = datetime.date(df['dt'][ind])
        paramThree = PROCESS_TIME

        dataTuple = (paramOne, paramTwo, paramThree)
        data.append(dataTuple)

    # Insert many
    target_tb = 'test_db'
    script = "insert into {tb} values (:1, :2, :3)".format(tb=target_tb)
    cursor.executemany(script, data)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some issue which need to be fixed

- currently you should get the error

  ```py
  AttributeError: module'pandas' has no attribute 'dataframe'
  ```

  because **dataframe** should be renamed as **DataFrame**
- and you should get another error

  ```py
  TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object
  ```

  rather you can use **datetime.strptime**
- concatenate the connection string like this
  **`'Test/123456@127.0.0.1:1521/testDb'`**
- the columns *except for* **id**(*already generated automatically*)
  next to the INSERT statement should explicitly be listed
- moreover, using exception handling, and sprinkling some ***print*** commands
  within the code ,*in order to follow what's going on*, is a remarkable
  habit to be considered

So, overall code might be rewritten as

```py
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd  
from datetime import *

apiToDf={
    'strMsg':[
        'AA',
        'BB',
        'CC',
        'DD'
    ],
    'dt':[
        '2022-02-01',
        '2022-02-02',
        '2022-02-03',
        '2022-02-04'
    ]
}

df=pd.DataFrame(apiToDf)


data = []
process_time = datetime.now()

for ind in df.index:
    dataList = []
    
    dataList.append(df['strMsg'][ind])    
    dataList.append(datetime.strptime(df['dt'][ind], "%Y-%m-%d")) 
    dataList.append(process_time)
    data.append(dataList)

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('Test/123456@127.0.0.1:1521/testDb')
try:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    target_tb = 'test_db'
    script = "INSERT INTO {tb}(strMsg,dt,dt_time) VALUES(:1, :2, :3)".format(tb=target_tb)
    cursor.executemany(script, data)
    cursor.close()
except Exception as err:
    print('Error', err)
else:
    conn.commit()
    
conn.close()
```